# How do we inline title next to the legend in Chart Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, legend-properties

i am new to the chart js , i am facing the issues ,like how do we inline title next to the legend in Chart Js.

[Please Check The Image to view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfvJr.png)

Comment: Check the documentation on how to align the title here - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html#align

Comment: i have checked it , but you align at top , right , left , botton , but cannot take it next to legends.

Comment: You may have to align it right then modify the padding?